# window.requestFileSystem not firing in Cordova 3.5 android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am having a javascript code like this:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    alert("In device ready begin..");
    var base64Str = ""; //This I get dynamically
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, gotFS, fail);
    alert("In device ready end..");
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    alert("Got fs...")
    fileSystem.root.getFile("test.pdf", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function fail(error) {
    alert(error.code);
}
```

The problem is none of the events get fired I get the first alert in `onDeviceReady()` function. But I won't get other alerts. 
I already have this `org.apache.cordova.file` plugin in my plugins directory. I tried with `cordova prepare android` and did `cordova run android`. I also re-installed plugin, but still same issue. I am having cordova version `3.5.0-0.2.7` not sure if it is issue with cordova version? I am not sure what's the reason this is not working? Can anyone please guide me in this? Any help in this is highly appreciated since I have stuck in this long (and yes I also tried the similar questions in SO).

Comment: did you reach at js ? what error or log you got in console ? can you please paste log here ?

Comment: Do you have the appropriate permissions set in your configuration files for file system access? Also if the second _alert_ (_In device ready end_) doesn't fire at all, it means that there happens JavaScript error before it such as _LocalFileSystem_ is undefined.

Comment: @sanfor what is the permission I have to add? Since I am beginner  have added lot of permissions one of them is `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` am I correct?

Comment: if you used CLI for plugin you dont need to add permission and feature if not you have to add manually in androidmanifest.xml file

Comment: @DhwanikGandhi I have not manually added. I think when I install one of the plugin, it may have added.